# How do I talk to my TransportAgent?

Tags: exchange-transport-agents

So I have my TransportAgent (sort of) working. How do I talk to it to configure it? And I need to allow individual users to make settings for their account (like an anti-virus being given a white-list for a specific user). I need this for Exchange 2007/2010/2013 so I assume EWS is out. I would like to have:

1. I can write an Outlook AddIn that communicates including the user
   identification so I know who to set things for.
2. A web page that
   provides the same (part of the web mail_server/owa web page is
   fine).
3. A means for administrators to set both system config and
   individual user settings. Using whatever means for the U.I. that is
   standard.

Also, is there a good book out there that covers all of writing TransportAgents, including questions like these?

Comment: EWS is available for Exchange 2007 as well, although a lot of EWS functionality was added with SP1 (for Exchange 2007), so it might be slightly limited without the service pack.

Comment: @Halvard I'm ok with requiring SP1. If EWS is available, is that the best way to go?

Comment: I just know that you can use EWS on Exchange 2007.  I don't know enough about the topic otherwise to give a useful opinion :)